# Django asgi Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock deployment error

Tags: django, gunicorn, uvicorn

my run command for django asgi application using gunicorn looks like this:

```
gunicorn -b '0.0.0.0:8000' myproject.asgi:application -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --access-logfile /logs/access.log --access-logformat "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s %(r)s %(s)s %(b)s %(f)s" >> /logs/error.log
```

When I try to access any endpoint of the application, I get ***Single thread executor already being used, would deadlock*** error.

I am using following package versions:

```
Django=3.2.4
asgiref==3.4.0
uvicorn==0.15.0
gunicorn==20.1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing <s>:application</s> from the gunicorn run command as follows:

```
gunicorn -b '0.0.0.0:8000' myproject.asgi -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --access-logfile /logs/access.log --access-logformat "%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s %(r)s %(s)s %(b)s %(f)s" >> /logs/error.log
```

Comment: i did the same thing, and i sill have the same error.

Comment: can you share your error message here?